# TrackMenuPopup : popup menu keeps disappearing

Tags: c++, c, winapi, contextmenu, popupmenu

I've created a popup menu which will show when user click on taskbar icon by using [TrackPopupMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
The code works fine until I click outside the menu to cancel select item. Then whenever I left/right click the icon, the menu pops up and immediately disappear before I see it (looks like TrackPopupMenu is immediately return 0). MDSN told the way to fix by adding `PostMessage(hDlg, WM_NULL, 0, 0);` after TrackPopupMenu, but it doesn't work.

Here's my code :

```
case WM_LBUTTONUP :
case WM_RBUTTONUP :
            POINT p;
            GetCursorPos(&p);
            HMENU hPopupMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
            AppendMenu(hPopupMenu, MF_ENABLED, ID_ADDMUSIC,    L"Add music"   );
            AppendMenu(hPopupMenu, MF_ENABLED, ID_REMOVEMUSIC, L"Remove music");
            SetForegroundWindow(msgInfo->hwnd);
            result = TrackPopupMenu(hPopupMenu, TPM_BOTTOMALIGN | TPM_RIGHTALIGN | TPM_NONOTIFY |
                                                TPM_RETURNCMD | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON | TPM_VERNEGANIMATION,
                                                p.x, p.y, 0, msgInfo->hwnd, NULL);
            PostMessageW(msgInfo->hwnd, WM_NULL, 0, 0);
            DestroyMenu(hPopupMenu);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your checking for `WM_LBUTTONUP` and `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` is not the right way to do this.
In creating the taskbar icon we specify a call back message.
It is this message that must be checked and in that message check the `LPARAM` for `WM_LBUTTONUP` and `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an icon for your app in the tray?

Tray icons send a WM_SHELLNOTIFY message for different things, wParm  is 0 and you can test for WM_RBUTTONDOWN | WM_RBUTTONUP in lParam.

Create the menu once at startup and delete when you close you tray app.